# not capturing escape characters in renderPrint of R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

In my R Shiny app, I would like to properly display text that contains escape characters (e.g. \n \t ...)

in my ui.R:

```
textOutput('textDisplay')
```

in my server.R:

```
output$textDisplay <- renderPrint({cat('line1\nline2')})
```

But the Shiny just displays 'line1 line2'

Normally, cat('line1\nline2') would correctly treat \n as a newline. Can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`renderPrint` is more fun in a way, as it will output HTML just as it is written. So your server.R should read:

```
output$textDisplay <- renderPrint({cat('line1<br/>line2')})
```

to do what you expect it to do.